# How to round by a total digits(including integer part) instead of a fixed digit in python?

Tags: python, rounding, digits

I wonder if there is any easy way to round a double number to a total digits in python?
For example, I want 3 digits in total, so 
I want to 1.523 to be 1.52 ,  and 23.45 to be 23.5,  and 108,9 to be 109

thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean "round" or "format"? To put it another way, what is the type of the result you seek (`float` or `str`)? Also, what answer would you want for `.0005` or `10005`?

Comment: `round(23.45, 1) == 23.4` and not `23.5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sround = lambda x,d: round(x,d - int(math.ceil(math.log10(abs(x)))))

sround(1.2345, 3) # 1.23
sround(12345.67, 3) # 12300.0
sround(-.01234, 1) # -0.01
sround(199, 1) # 200.0
```